# Подсчет строк MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть запрос в базу данных для получения списка заказов.

```
SELECT 
    `orders`.*, 
    SUM(`pto`.`amount` *  `pto`.`price`) + `orders`.`delivery_cost` - `orders`.`discount` as `full_sum`
FROM 
    `orders`
LEFT JOIN `product_to_order` AS `pto` ON(`pto`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`) 
WHERE 
    `orders`.`type` = 'sending'
GROUP BY 
    `orders`.`id` 
HAVING `full_sum` LIKE '%140%' 
ORDER BY `orders`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

`orders.delivery_cost` - Цена доставки

`orders.discount` - Скидка

`pto.price` - Цена товара

`pto.amount` - Количество товара

Раньше не приходилось фильтровать заказы по сумме, а теперь нужна такая опция и я прибег к использованию `HAVING`.
Данные нужны для постраничной навигации(пагинатора).
Вопрос как получить количество всех записей, которые подходят под данный фильтр?

Comment: *SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tells MySQL to calculate how many rows there would be in the result set, disregarding any LIMIT clause. The number of rows can then be retrieved with SELECT FOUND_ROWS().* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(*) as ocnt from (SELECT orders.id as oid,  
  SUM(pto.amount *  pto.price) + orders.delivery_cost - 
      orders.discount as full_sum
  FROM orders
  LEFT JOIN product_to_order AS pto ON(pto.order_id = orders.id) 
  WHERE orders.type = 'sending'
  GROUP BY oid
  HAVING full_sum LIKE '%140%') as tab1
```

АЛСО, я конечно не знаю как там что у вас, но LIKE предполагается использовать со строковыми данными - для всех типов чисел гораздо удобнее (и главное - быстрее) установить обычные диапазоны с использованием <,<=,>,>=,=, IN : 
HAVING full_sum > 100.0 AND full_sum <= 160.0 - например